# Gremlin: Get all vertices hasLabel 'model' and their children with all properties

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a graph which should have the following json structure

```
{
    "models": [
    {
        "name": "Model1",
        "id": 19,
        "diagram": [
        {
            "name": "Diagram1",
            "id": "34"
        },
        {
            "name": "Diagram2",
            "id": "36"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Model2",
        "id": 14,
        "diagram": [
        {
            "name": "Diagram2",
            "id": "32"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Here is my sample graph:

```java
g.addV('org').property('name', 'Org_seppmed').as('org1').addV('org').property('name', 'Org_siemens').as('org2').addV('user').property('name', 'U_Sebastian').as('user1').addV('user').property('name', 'U_Jaroslaw').as('user2').addV('user').property('name', 'U_Jürgen').as('user3').addV('user').property('name', 'U_Carsten').as('user4').addV('user').property('name', 'U_DevUser').as('user5').addE('administratedBy').from('org1').to('user1').addE('hasEmployee').from('org1').to('user2').addE('hasEmployee').from('org1').to('user3').addE('hasEmployee').from('org2').to('user4').addE('hasEmployee').from('org1').to('user5').addE('hasGuest').from('org1').to('user4').addV('project').property('name', 'P_Bremsen').as('projectmbt1').addV('project').property('name', 'P_Blinker').as('projectmbt2').addE('owns').from('user1').to('projectmbt1').addE('owns').from('user2').to('projectmbt2').addE('writes').from('user2').to('projectmbt1').addE('writes').from('user3').to('projectmbt1').addE('reads').from('user4').to('projectmbt1').addE('writes').from('user1').to('projectmbt2').addE('writes').from('user3').to('projectmbt2').addV('model').property('name', 'M_Bremse').as('modelmbt1').addV('model').property('name', 'M_Blinker').as('modelmbt2').addV('model').property('name', 'M_Bremse2').as('modelmbt3').addE('has').from('projectmbt1').to('modelmbt1').addE('has').from('projectmbt1').to('modelmbt3').addE('has').from('projectmbt2').to('modelmbt2').addV('diagram').property('name', 'D_D1').as('diagramd1').addV('diagram').property('name', 'D_D2').as('diagramd2').addV('diagram').property('name', 'D_D3').as('diagramd3').addV('diagram').property('name', 'D_D1').as('diagramd4').addV('testsuite').property('name', 'T_TestD1').as('testsuited1').addE('has').from('modelmbt1').to('diagramd1').addE('has').from('modelmbt1').to('diagramd2').addE('has').from('modelmbt2').to('diagramd3').addE('has').from('modelmbt3').to('diagramd4').addE('has').from('modelmbt1').to('testsuited1').addV('initial').as('initMBT1D1').addV('precondition').as('preMBT1D1').addV('teststep').property('name', 'N_Blinking left').as('node1MBT1D1').addV('teststep').property('name', 'N_Blinking right').as('node2MBT1D1').addV('teststep').property('name', 'N_Hazard flashers').as('node3MBT1D1').addV('teststep').property('name', 'N_Emergency flashers').as('node4MBT1D1').addV('teststep').property('name', 'N_Blinking off').as('node5MBT1D1').addV('node').as('connodeMBT1D1').addV('postcondition').as('postMBT1D1').addV('final').as('finalMBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('initMBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('preMBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('node1MBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('node2MBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('node3MBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('node4MBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('node5MBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('connodeMBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('postMBT1D1').addE('has').from('diagramd1').to('finalMBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('initMBT1D1').to('preMBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('preMBT1D1').to('node1MBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('preMBT1D1').to('node2MBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('preMBT1D1').to('node3MBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('preMBT1D1').to('node4MBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('preMBT1D1').to('node5MBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('node1MBT1D1').to('postMBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('postMBT1D1').to('node1MBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('node2MBT1D1').to('postMBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('node3MBT1D1').to('postMBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('node4MBT1D1').to('postMBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('node5MBT1D1').to('postMBT1D1').addE('pointsTo').from('postMBT1D1').to('connodeMBT1D1').addE('linksTo').from('connodeMBT1D1').to('diagramd2').addE('pointsTo').from('connodeMBT1D1').to('finalMBT1D1').addV('initial').as('initMBT1D2').addV('teststep').property('name', 'N_Trigger left').as('node1MBT1D2').addV('teststep').property('name', 'N_Trigger right').as('node2MBT1D2').addV('verificationpoint').property('name', 'N_Triggercheck').as('node3MBT1D2').addV('final').as('finalMBT1D2').addE('has').from('diagramd2').to('initMBT1D2').addE('has').from('diagramd2').to('node1MBT1D2').addE('has').from('diagramd2').to('node2MBT1D2').addE('has').from('diagramd2').to('node3MBT1D2').addE('has').from('diagramd2').to('finalMBT1D2').addE('pointsTo').from('initMBT1D2').to('node1MBT1D2').addE('pointsTo').from('initMBT1D2').to('node2MBT1D2').addE('pointsTo').from('node1MBT1D2').to('node3MBT1D2').addE('pointsTo').from('node2MBT1D2').to('node3MBT1D2').addE('pointsTo').from('node3MBT1D2').to('finalMBT1D2')
```

Now I am trying to find a query to get above structure:

```java
g.V().hasLabel("model").out().hasLabel("diagram").path().by(elementMap())
```

The result is like:

```
==>path[{id=12384, label=model, name=Model2}, {id=28904, label=diagram, name=Diagram2}]
==>path[{id=37056, label=model, name=Model1}, {id=16448, label=diagram, name=Diagram1}]
==>path[{id=37056, label=model, name=Model1}, {id=24808, label=diagram, name=Diagram1}]
```

My expectation was to get a `Map<Model, List<Diagram>>`. But i get for each diagram of a model a complete new entry, instead of adding all related diagrams to a model.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a Map you will need to `group` using the model as the key. Something like shown below. Obviously, you will not really want to use the `label` but something that identifies the class of the model, if you have such a property, such as `name`.

```java
g.V().hasLabel("model").
      group().
        by('name').
        by(out().hasLabel("diagram").path().by(elementMap()).fold())
```

**EDITED after discussion in comments:**

If you do not want the whole `path` in the result but just the unique diagram nodes and their properties, the query can be amended to as shown below. This version also adds all of the properties from the label node as the group (map) key.

```java
g.V().hasLabel("model").
      group(). 
        by(elementMap()).
        by(out().hasLabel("diagram").elementMap().fold())
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this query gives me only one path of model to diagram. But I need all Models with their children (diagrams). And from all result vertices their properties

Comment: Here is my playground: https://gremlify.com/nbvke97vu

Comment: just add a `fold` after `elementMap())` then and it should be OK. I updated the answer.

Comment: Please provide the `addV` and `addE` steps to build a representative sample graph if the answer is not sufficient. Links to Gremlify are useful but SO posts ultimately need to be able to stand on their own when found by people later and it is easier to build a tested answer having the sample graph as part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I have added the sample graph to my inital post.

Comment: So can you please clarify what you want the output to be like, it's hard to tell exactly from the JSON. For each model do you want the chain of nodes until a leaf node or something else? The code in my answer will give you all the diagrams for each model. Do you just want to wrap all that inside a structure called `models` ?

Comment: Hi. I need an output like the json above. At the moment gives your query for every diagram a model part. What I need is all models (parent) with their diagrams(children) and all properties of every vertex from the result vertices. And without duplication of model.

Comment: Does removing the `path` step from the query give what you want?  If so I will update the answer.

Comment: No. "error":"org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.HasStep cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.ByModulating"

Comment: Sorry I meant remove the entire path construct including the by() and just keep `elementMap().fold()` after the `hasLabel`

Comment: Ok. We modified this a litte bit. Now we get a result which is as close as possible to our expectation: g.V().hasLabel("model"). group(). by(elementMap().fold()). by(out().hasLabel("diagram").elementMap().fold())

What you think about it?

Comment: Good to hear that got it working. I was about to update the answer anyway so I'll do it to align with what worked for you in case others with a similar question find this post. I think what you are doing, now I understand better what you were trying to achieve makes sense from a Gremlin query perspective. I removed the `fold` after `elementMap` for the `group` key as I don't think that should be needed.